# Drupal 7 node relationships when creating new content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, entityreference

Say I have 2 content types "Artist" and "Biography". I can use Entity Reference to link one Biography with one Artist (it's a one to one relationship).

Now when creating a new Artist, can I have a tab or a link to add an artist biography directly, instead of having to create the artist first, then the biography, and link it with an artist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of one for Entity Reference but if you can swap that out in favour of the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module you can use [References dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) which would be suited to your use case:

> This module extends reference fields like the user and node reference fields by adding links to add, edit and search for references through a dialog. This allows for a workflow where the user can create all the references to a node at the same time as she is creating it, a process which sometimes get's a bit backwards, when a user for instance needs to create all the facts for an article.

If you're changing to a different relationship module, there's also the [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module which:

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.

It embeds the add/edit form for the referenced entities into the primary entity's form so you can create multiple related entities from the same page. It also has support for nodes built right in.

Comment: Thank you. Using Inline Entity Form with Entity Reference worked fine!